# multi-tenant tutorial, example?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, multi-tenant

I'm building an app that needs to create a database per custumer.
I'm using wcf and EF for this. But I can't find a decent example or tutorial about a multi-tenent design.

Right now I'm thinking of doing something like this in  wcf:

```
public product(int id,LicenseID)
{
  dal = new dal(LicenseID)  <--create connection with DB from a specific License
  dal.getProduct(id) <-- getProduct from that database 
}
```

Am I doing the right thing here, or are the standard better ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

there is a post on blog of Rowan Miller (Program Manager for the ADO.NET Entity Framework team at Microsoft) with an example of multi-tenant

http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first